# How to read slots from watson assistant in python

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson

I created a slot that prompts the user to enter a gender in watson assistant I have provided the values , now I want to call the same slot in my python flask code . I am able to call individual dialogues from python but for multiple slots I am not able to get the Watson output inside the python code.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I have used this query to get response from watson assistant response=conversation_client.message(workspace_id=conversation_workspace_id, message_input=bot_input) , In watson assistant, I have set slots to handle request from user but when I query through this statement inside my python code it doesn't give me a proper response .